# Python Callback Syntax Error

Tags: python, split, callback

Let me start off with the code . Note, all variables present in the code are well defined.

```
call(['youtube-upload', '--title='song + " ~ ["+movie_name +"]", '--description="Hi there!\nDon\'t forget to enjoy :)"', '--category="Song"', '--default-language="en"', '--playlist "'+xx+'"', song2file(song)+'.mp4'], shell=False)
```

error(syntax error):
[image: Syntax Error]

Please Help

Comment: try with `'--title='+song`

Answer (score 3):

missing '+' between '--title=' and song.

```
call(['youtube-upload', '--title='+ song + " ~ ["+movie_name +"]", '--description="Hi there!\nDon\'t forget to enjoy :)"', '--category="Song"', '--default-language="en"', '--playlist "'+xx+'"', song2file(song)+'.mp4'], shell=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `+` between `'--title='` and `song`. However you should really use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of string addition. Makes it easier to read, faster and reduces the risk of missing `+` or mismatching quotes.

For example:

```
call(['youtube-upload', 
      '--title={song} ~ [{movie_name}]'.format(song=song, movie_name=movie_name), 
      '--description="Hi there!\nDon\'t forget to enjoy :)"', 
      '--category="Song"', 
      '--default-language="en"', 
      '--playlist "{xx}"'.format(xx=xx), 
      '{filename}.mp4'.format(filename=song2file(song))], 
     shell=False)
```

In case you have Python 3.6+ then [`f`-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) will shorten this considerably:

```
call(['youtube-upload', 
      f'--title={song} ~ [{movie_name}]', 
      '--description="Hi there!\nDon\'t forget to enjoy :)"', 
      '--category="Song"', 
      '--default-language="en"', 
      f'--playlist "{xx}"', 
      f'{song2file(song)}.mp4'], 
     shell=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to the [`f`-strings PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498). Interesting read.